# Including title of document in external reference

Tags: cross-referencing, xr

I'm currently using xr to reference external documents. It's good in as much as I get linked via hyperref to the relevant result, but it would be helpful if it displayed the title of the document containing the result I'm linking to, as well as the number of the result itself. Is this possible?

Sorry for not providing an example, the following documents show my current setup:

File A:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}\label{Foo}
Bar.
\end{document}
```

File B:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\externaldocument{fileA}

\begin{document}
\ref{Foo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

May be there is an option in hyperref package but I wouldn't waste the time with hundreds of pages in hyperref doc, so there is a solution derived by reverse engineering. FileB:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\def\eref{\@ifstar \@refstar \Toref}
\def\Toref #1{\NR@setref {#1}\firstplusthree {#1}}
\makeatother
\def\firstplusthree#1#2#3#4#5{#1: #3}

\externaldocument{fileA}

\begin{document}
\eref{Foo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, it's great except I wanted the external references to show the title of the document being referenced (either from the \title command, or from some custom command). I ended up inserting xr prefixes into my labels, and using a modified prettyref (with ":" replaced by "-") to detect them.